# Edit a data item in Cognos to display as two digits

Tags: cognos-10

**Disclaimer**: I am a Cognos newbie.

I want to format a data item in Cognos (Report Studio 10.2) to always display as 2 digits. For example, if the value of the data item in 2, I want it to be displayed as 02. How can I achieve this?

I have tried

1. Format$([my_data_item], "00")
2. Format([my_data_item], '00') - w/o the dollar sign

None worked.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to format the contents of the data item itself or do you want to format the representation of the data item in a e.g. tabular list? The former is only weakly supported, the latter is well supported, but it is not done using built-in functions but using properties.

Comment: I will need to append this data item with another text item. That's why I will have to format the data item and not the representation on the list. Basically this data item is the part after the decimal. So let's say if the value is $1.02 M (M for million), this data item is the part after the decimal. This is legacy report and redoing it more elegantly in not an option. That's why I am trying to format the 02 as "02" and not "2".

Comment: You could insert two data items into one column and still use the advanced formatting for the individual data items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcus ...thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

I was able to use the round function in the query with a CASE statement and it served my purpose with very little modification to the original report. Note to any new Cognos developer would be leave formatting to the report page and not the query.

```
case when [TRANSFORMATION VIEW].[SOME_FACT].[DOLLAR_VAL]<>-99999 then
    case when [TRANSFORMATION VIEW].[SOME_FACT].[DOLLAR_VAL] >= 1000000 then 
        round( [TRANSFORMATION VIEW].[SOME_FACT].[DOLLAR_VAL] /1000000, 2)
    else 
        round([TRANSFORMATION VIEW].[SOME_FACT].[DOLLAR_VAL],0)
    end
end
```

Then on the report itself, I formatted the data item as Numeric and didn't change any of the default settings. That did the magic. The reason why I have round([TRANSFORMATION VIEW].[SOME_FACT].[DOLLAR_VAL],0) is because I don't want to display cents in the dollar amount.